# How to fix crash issue in NFC Tag Writer app due to UnsupportedOperationException in android

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I m trying to implement NFC writer app in **android 11 in wear os**, but im getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when im trying to add this below code in on resume callback ,can some one please help me to fix this issue

```
  override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        nfcAdapter?.let {
            enableNFCInForeground(it, this, javaClass)
        }

    }
        override fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
             nfcAdapter?.let {
                    disableNFCInForeground(it, this)
                }
        }
```

and i used this code for enableNFCInForeground

```
private fun <T> enableNFCInForeground(nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter, activity: Activity, classType: Class<T>) {
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            activity, 0,
            Intent(activity, classType).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0
        )
       // val nfcIntentFilter = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)
        val nfcIntentFilter = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED).apply {
            try {
                addDataType("text/plain")
            } catch (e: IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException) {
                throw RuntimeException("fail", e)
            }
        }
        val filters = arrayOf(nfcIntentFilter)

        val techLists =
            arrayOf(arrayOf(Ndef::class.java.name), arrayOf(NdefFormatable::class.java.name))

        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techLists)
    }
```

and for disableNFCInForeground

```
   private fun disableNFCInForeground(nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter, activity: Activity) {
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity)
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the stacktrace from the crash.

Comment: Also, you say that you have a function called `enableNFCInForeground`, but then you posted one named `enableForegroundDispatch`. Please fix the code in your question so that the names match.

Comment: updateed my question

Comment: I did not think that using it as an NFC reader was supported on Wear OS devices, only card emulation via Google Pay or via HCE.